# Prevent blocking of redirect from https to http in service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have been working on implementing a service worker to add some caching benefits to our site and all has been going well apart from one particular page on the site.

This page is linked to as https://domain/path  but a server side redirect looks to redirect this to http://domain/path/ and this point the service worker is blocking the request. When the link is clicked the page puts out a `This webpage is not available` error and the console shows the following:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.com/service-worker.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://domain.com/path/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Ideally we will be looking to ensure that redirect stays on https, but while that issue is resolved is there a way of working around this within the service worker?

Comment: How exactly is the service worker blocking your request? Your error message says that the request to the `service-worker.js` did not, as it should, load on the http page.

Comment: Without a service worker the browser would just follow the redirect. When the service worker is handling fetches the redirect gets blocked

Comment: Does the error happens for other files than `https://domain.com/service-worker.js`?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, current implementation prevents the SW to mix content. Chrome explain why at: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=448672#c4 stating:

> So every request using fetch() must be blocked, because fetch is not an optionally-blockable request context.

However, I raised the question to the specification committee as it seems to be against the current specification. You can follow the discussion and read the rationale behind at: https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/813